# How to show an image preview with a crop grid to have user drag image to fixed size

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React-Dropzone and currently using React-Easy-Crop to try to constrain an image to a specific size. I need to present the user with a way to crop the image to a specific height and width within an image preview.

```
<div
    className="form-group"
    style={{ marginBottom: "10px" }}
>
    <Dropzone
    style={{ width: "460px" }}
    data-cy="drag-and-drop"
    accept="image/*"
    onDrop={acceptedFiles => {
        const imageErrors = [];

        // do nothing if no files
        if (acceptedFiles.length === 0) return;

        console.log("acceptedFiles", acceptedFiles);

        async function loadEdit(img) {
        if (img.width < 1440 || img.height < 360) {
            imageErrors.push(
            "This image must have a minimum Width of 1440px and a minimum Height of 360px"
            );
        }

        console.log({
            width: img.width,
            height: img.height
        });

        if (imageErrors.length > 0) {
            alert(imageErrors.join(", "));
        }
        }

        const img = new Image();
        img.addEventListener(
        "load",
        () =>
            loadEdit(img).then(() => {
            if (imageErrors.length > 0) {
                console.log("errors found");
                return;
            }

            // Automatically set Status field
            setFieldValue("statusselect", {
                label: "Active",
                value: 1
            });

            values.attachments = [];

            setFieldValue(
                "attachments",
                values.attachments.concat(acceptedFiles)
            );
            }),
        false
        );

        img.src = acceptedFiles[0].preview;
    }}
    >
    {({ isDragActive, isDragReject }) => {
        if (isDragActive) {
        return "This file is authorized";
        }

        if (isDragReject) {
        return "This file is not authorized";
        }

        if (values.attachments.length === 0) {
        return (
            <div style={overlayStyle}>
            click or drag Files here to upload.
            </div>
        );
        }

        return values.attachments.map(file => (
        <img src={file.preview} alt="file" style={{ width: "1440px", height: "330px"}} />
        ));
    }}
    </Dropzone>
    <span>* Minimum Image size required: 1440x360px</span>
</div>
```

In my image tag, how do I set the image to a specific size even tho the image is constrained to no less then 1440px by 360px? I tried to set the width and height but that won't work. I also need to add an overlay like react-easy-crop or use that.

Any ideas would really help me out. Thanks.

Comment: It's an old question but maybe still relevant.. You can put the container of react-easy-crop (`<Cropper />`) at the same position (using `position: absolute`) as the `<Dropzone />` so when user will drop an image there, the `Cropper` will contains the image at the exact same position. Next step will be add the preview, you can't do this just with `<img />` tag and css modification because you need to cut and move the image so you can use `canvas`, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56275119/863110