# How to use react-easy-crop to reflect position changes from react-easy-crop to live image rendered in another div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

After selecting an image i am rendering it in two places, one is in react-easy-crop(4:3 aspect ratio) and another is in separate div(960w*510h).so when ever i change my crop position in react-easy-crop.my another div should move it position as well.listening to onchangecrop event from react-easy-crop

```
onCropChange = (crop) => {
    //crop has x and y of translated value in px
    pageObj = `${crop.x * -1}% ${crop.y * -1}%`.toLowerCase();
    //pageObj will have x and y position in percentage.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to display a preview image. If so, you can use a `canvas` to manipulate the original image and cut and re-posisioning it.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Cropper from 'react-easy-crop'

export class App extends Component {
  canvas = {}

  state = {
    image: 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3d721f4c46282afc254f3ea0cd05df30?s=170&d=identicon&r=PG',
    crop: { x: 0, y: 0 },
    zoom: 1,
    aspect: 4 / 3,
    croppedAreaPixels: {}
  }

  onCropChange = crop => {
    this.setState({ crop })
  }

  onCropComplete = (croppedArea, croppedAreaPixels) => {
    console.log(croppedArea, croppedAreaPixels);
    const ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    const image = document.getElementById('source');

    this.canvas.setAttribute('width', croppedAreaPixels.width);
    this.canvas.setAttribute('height', croppedAreaPixels.height);
    ctx.drawImage(image, croppedAreaPixels.x, croppedAreaPixels.y, croppedAreaPixels.width, croppedAreaPixels.height, 0, 0, croppedAreaPixels.width, croppedAreaPixels.height);
    this.setState({
      croppedAreaPixels 
    })
  }

  onZoomChange = zoom => {
    this.setState({ zoom })
  }

  render() {
    const { image, croppedAreaPixels, crop, zoom, aspect } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <img id="source" style={{display: 'none'}} src={image} />
        <canvas ref={canvas => this.canvas = canvas} width={croppedAreaPixels.width} height={croppedAreaPixels.height}></canvas>
        <Cropper
          image={image}
          crop={crop}
          zoom={zoom}
          aspect={aspect}
          onCropChange={this.onCropChange}
          onCropComplete={this.onCropComplete}
          onZoomChange={this.onZoomChange}
        />
      </>
    )
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

And working demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-easy-crop-with-preview

And with `background-position` approach, instead of `canvas`.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-easy-crop-with-preview-with-bg-position

Comment: Thanks mate. thats my actual requirement.I have few other requirement which is **bold**  1) can we use onCropchange event from react-easy-crop and do the same? 2)Instead of creating new canvas ,is it possible to position the image using onCropchange (crop ) x and y value with background position and get the same result (I have tried but it seems like not possible ,please share your suggestion).Thanks a lot .

Comment: 1. It's more tricky because `onCropchange` doesn't return the coordinates as `onCropComplete` so more calculation need to be done to get the tight coordinates (It's a great feature request you can ask them). 2. I added this to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your awesome solution.Will sure drop a feature request.

Comment: Sure. My pleasure :) If you already open a PR, you can ask for preview option too :)

Comment: I have problem with this library. After crop success, I have another state and change it but click then the area crop lost and only 0px area crop. Can anyone help me resolve it?